# Explicación sobre objeto implícito y objeto explícito

Tags: java, string, objeto

Quiero saber porqué, cuando comparo dos objetos `String` creados con el mismo valor de forma implícita en Java, me retorna un valor `true`, pero al crearlos de manera explícita me retorna un valor `false`.

```
String name1 = new String("Rojo");
String name2 = new String("Rojo");

System.out.println(name1 == name2); // false

String name3 = "Rojo";
String name4 = "Rojo";

System.out.println(name3 == name4); // true
```

Comment: [info](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/java-string-literal-vs-string-object/)

Comment: por desempeño. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Esto se debe a la forma en que estás comparando ambos objetos y a la forma de crearlos.

No poseo todo el conocimiento necesario para explicar detalles demasiado técnicos sobre el funcionamiento de la [`JVM` (Máquina Virtual de Java)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/es/i/7.3?topic=platform-java-virtual-machine), el [`Heap` y `Stack`](https://codingornot.com/diferencias-entre-heap-y-stack) o la internación de cadenas, por lo que simplificaré mi respuesta a lo poco que sé.

Sucede que acá, tenemos dos escenarios, uno es el del literal de cadena `"Rojo"` y otro es el del objeto `java.lang.String("Rojo")`.

---

> **Literales:**

De acuerdo con [esta entrada](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/java-tutorial/literals-in-java#:%7E:text=Literals%20in%20Java%20are%20a,assigned%20now%20to%20a%20variable.) los literales en Java son valores constantes especiales, que pueden ser asignados a una variable o ser utilizados directamente.

Cuando creas una cadena de esta forma `"Rojo"` lo que hace Java es verificar si ya existe en algo llamado [`Pool String`](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/java-string-pool-un-concepto-importante/) (Piscina de cadenas) que no e más que un área de memoria reservada para alojar dichas cadenas. Si existe, Java la retorna sin hacer nada más, si no, entonces Java la aloja en dicha piscina y luego la retorna.

Es decir, que siempre que hagas referencia a `"Rojo"` Java te devolverá el mismo objeto con la misma dirección de memoria, y esto es un medio de optimización aplicado por la `JVM`. Puede ser `"Azul"`, `"Perro"` o un literal de cadena vacío `""`:

```
System.out.println("Rojo"  == "Rojo");  // true
System.out.println("Azul"  == "Azul");  // true
System.out.println("Perro" == "Perro"); // true
System.out.println(""      == "");      // true
```

---

> **java.lang.String:**

Acá ya cambiamos las reglas, ya que `String` es un objeto y, como cualquier objeto en Java, cada vez que creas uno mediante el operador `new` (`new String()`) lo que hace Java es alojar un nuevo objeto en memoria con una dirección única.

Para entender mejor esto, te propongo un ejemplo sencillo con código:

```
Object obj1 = new Object();
Object obj2 = new Object();

System.out.println(obj1 == obj2); // false
```

Ambos `obj1` y `obj2` son del mismo tipo `Object` pero apuntan a direcciones de memoria diferentes y por ende no son iguales.

En cambio:

```
Object obj1 = new Object();
Object obj2 = obj1;

System.out.println(obj1 == obj2); // true
```

Muestra un caso en que `obj` y `obj2` apuntan al mismo objeto con la misma dirección de memoria y por ende son iguales.

Sucede lo mismo con el objeto `String`:

```
String obj1 = new String("Rojo");
String obj2 = new String("Rojo");

System.out.println(obj1 == obj2); // false

String obj1 = new String("Rojo");
String obj2 = obj1;

System.out.println(obj1 == obj2); // true
```

Ya que de esta forma no estás comparando el valor de cadena como tal sino la instancia de la clase `String`.

Por esto, la clase `String` expone el método [`equals(String)`](http://www.w3api.com/Java/String/equals/) que sí compara el valor de cadena contenido en dicho objeto.

```
String obj1 = new String("Rojo");
String obj2 = new String("Rojo");

System.out.println(obj1.equals(obj2)); // true
```

---

**Extensión:**

Imagina que tienes una caja llena de latas de pintura. Cuando haces:

```
String name1 = "Rojo";
String name2 = "Rojo";
```

Te estas refiriendo a la misma lata de pintura desde tu caja, de la misma marca de fabricante. Solo que te estás refiriendo a ella en distintos lugares e instantes, pero se trata de una misma lata con el mismo color y la misma marca referida múltiples veces. La estás reutilizando.

En cambio, cuando haces:

```
String name1 = new String("Rojo");
String name2 = new String("Rojo");
```

Te estas refiriendo a dos latas de pintura con el mismo color de pintura pero de distintos fabricantes y calidades. A simple vista el color parece el mismo, pero ambas latas presentan diferente origen, fórmula, calidad, etc. No hay reutilización.

Answer (score 0):

En java la comparación de objetos es por referencia. Es decir, cuando 2 objetos comparten el mismo espacio en memoria son iguales. Y los primitivos (como el int) se realizan por valor

Motivo por el cual pasa esto:

```
String name1 = new String("Rojo");
String name2 = new String("Rojo");
System.out.println(name1 == name2); // false: Comparación por referencia
System.out.println(name2.equals(name1)); //true: Comparación por valor
```

El otro caso:

```
String name3 = "Rojo";
String name4 = "Rojo";
System.out.println(name3 == name4); // true
```

Esto pasa porque `Rojo` se transforma en constante, el código anterior es lo mismo que:

```
String rojo_constate = "Rojo"; // o new String("Rojo")
String name3 = rojo_constate;
String name4 = rojo_constate;
System.out.println(name3 == name4); // true
```

Donde tanto `name3` y `name4` apuntan al mismo espacio en memoria dispuesto para `rojo_constate`

Según la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)

> Las expresiones de tipo constantes en tiempo de compilación siempre se
> "internan" para **compartir instancias únicas**

Comment: en le segundo caso no se transforma en constante, las literales de cadena son constantes

Comment: Me refiero a que el texto se transforma en constante cuando se compila

Comment: no se transforma en constante, ES constante

Comment: Es constante en tiempo de ejecución no antes

Comment: de hecho todas las literales de cadenas son constantes desde el tiempo de compilacion y eso ES antes

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas aprender más al respecto he hecho [un artículo más completo](https://javapro.org/programming-languages/java-string-inmutables-por-diseno/), pero aquí te pongo las partes esenciales:

Como dice [la documentacion de Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

Las Strings son constantes; sus valores no pueden ser cambiador después de que son creados. Debido a que los objetos `String` son inmutables pueden ser compartidos.

Cuando se diseñó le lenguaje se pensó que las cadenas fueran "internas", es decir que tienen instancias únicas compartidas. Recordemos que el (anti)patrón de diseño singleton no existía en ese momento, pero los creadores pensaron en una funcionalidad similar.
Para ello el método `intern()` de `String` nos habla de una *String pool*, un pozo de cadenas, inicialmente vacío.

En el 99% de los casos no tiene sentido usar `new String("mi cadena")` ya que crea una nueva instancia, que por supuesto al comparar con otra con el mismo contenido mediante == te dirá que son diferentes.
Es por ello que la forma recomendada de comparar cadenas aunque sea constantes es usar el método `equals` para evitar el caso improbable que haya dos instancias con el miso contenido.